# Where should the 2$\pi$ go in the Fourier Transform?

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, convention

In some lecture notes on Harmonic Analysis from Terence Tao [here](http://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Etao/254a.1.01w/notes1.dvi), he defines the fourier transform by $$\hat{f}(\tau)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-2\pi i t\tau}f(t)dt$$
and then says

> This is really the best place to put the $2\pi$; listen to the harmonic analysts and
> representation theorists on this one, and ignore the PDE people, physicists, and
> engineers!

But **why** is this the best spot for it?  It seems cleaner than having a factor of $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ or $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ in front of the integral.  But it isn't so clean that you  forget there is a $2\pi$ at all, like if you hide it in the measure $dt$.

Are there other reasons?  Better Reasons? Reasons that only reveal themselves after working in harmonic analysis for a while?  Any answers would be appreciated.

Comment: I think one reason why harmonic analysts and representation theorists like the $2\pi$ in the exponent is that that gives you $\mathcal{F}(f \ast g) = \mathcal{F}(f) \cdot \mathcal{F}(g)$, which is a **very** nice property. Plus, the symmetry between $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{F}^{-1}$ remains, i.e. it's an isometry still. The drawback is that you get $2\pi$ factors when you differentiate.

Answer (score 7):

There are conventions that are standard in different fields of application.  For example, mathematicians like the $1/\sqrt{2 \pi}$ factor because it makes the FT unitary.  Physicists like the $1/(2 \pi)$ factor because it helps them remember conservation laws that are deduced from Parseval's Theorem.  (I fit into this camp.)  And electrical engineers like the $2 \pi$ in the exponential because they like to operate in terms of cycles per second rather than with angular frequencies.

I may be over-generalizing, but as I have experience in all three camps, I think my opinion is grounded in some fact.

Comment: A nice answer, but you may want to amend "mathematicians" to something more specific, because according to the Terence Tao quote in the question harmonic analysts and representation theorists prefer the $2\pi$ in the exponential.