# Should `fourier transform of real data` be complex data?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

I am using `mathematica` and `python` to `fourier transform` the same `list`. Result as below:

##python

```
t = np.arange(10)
s = np.sin(0.15*2*np.pi*t)
S = np.fft.fft(s)
print(S)

[ 1.96261051+0.00000000e+00j  3.65687576-4.44089210e-16j
 -2.90211303+6.58456965e-16j -0.90211303+2.77704128e-16j
 -0.57919222+1.15109392e-16j -0.50952545-5.24550760e-18j
 -0.57919222-1.15109392e-16j -0.90211303-2.69216718e-16j
 -2.90211303-6.58456965e-16j  3.65687576+4.40847308e-16j]
```

##mathematica

```
t = Range[0, 9]
s = Sin[0.15*2*Pi*t]
Fourier[s,FourierParameters-> {1,-1}]
{1.96261, 3.65688, -2.90211, -0.902113, -0.579192, -0.509525, \
-0.579192, -0.902113, -2.90211, 3.65688}
```

I am not sure which one is correct.Should `fourier transform of real data` be complex data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the Fourier transform of real data can be complex.  Any odd integrable function will do the trick; for example, if $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1&0<x<1\\-1&-1<x<0\\0\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$ then $$\mathcal{F}(f)(\omega)=i\frac{\cos{\!(\omega)}-1}{\omega}$$ (up to a constant normalization factor; see e.g. [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/429451/where-should-the-2-pi-go-in-the-fourier-transform)) which is purely imaginary.

With that said, in your case, both Fourier transforms are real!  The reason Python and Mathematica are giving superficially different answers is just roundoff: the imaginary part of `3.65687576-4.44089210e-16j` is $$-4.44089210\cdot10^{-16}\approx 2^{-51}$$  [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) uses 53 bits of precision, so this is about four roundoff errors that did not cancel out.